# Java/Android: How do I simplify this complicated, nested if else and for loop codeblock?

Tags: java, android

I have two sections of code that are largely identical except for a few different constants that are used depending on the condition of the if statement. I would like to ask if anyone here knows how to simplify the code so that I don't have so much duplication of code.

Here's the code:

```
public static final int numLandscapeRows = 5;
public static final int numPortraitRows = 8;
public static final int numLandscapeImagesPerRow = 8;
public static final int numPortraitImagesPerRow = 5;
public static boolean imageViewLandscapeTracker[][] = new boolean[numLandscapeRows][numLandscapeImagesPerRow];
public static boolean imageViewPortraitTracker[][] = new boolean[numPortraitRows][numPortraitImagesPerRow];

if (screenWidth > screenHeight) {
    TableRow tableRow[] = new TableRow[numLandscapeRows];
    ImageView imageView[] = new ImageView[numLandscapeImagesPerRow];

    for (i = 0; i < numLandscapeRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numLandscapeImagesPerRow; j++) {
            imageView[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (imageViewLandscapeTracker[i-1][j-1] == false) {
                        imageViewLandscapeTracker[i-1][j-1] = true;
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.launcher);
                    } else {
                        imageViewLandscapeTracker[i-1][j-1] = false;
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                    }
        }
    }

} else {
    TableRow tableRow[] = new TableRow[numPortraitRows];
    ImageView imageView[] = new ImageView[numPortraitImagesPerRow];

    for (i = 0; i < numPortraitRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numPortraitImagesPerRow; j++) {
            imageView[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1] == false) {
                            imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1] = true;
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.launcher);
                        } else {
                            imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1] = false;
                            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                        }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's easy to understand. My Java is very basic so I don't think I can write very complicated code. But if there's anything you need clarification on, please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I ended up mostly using Jared's reducedFunction idea, passing it a `boolean[][] tracker` parameter that laz recommended. I also used glowcoder's suggestion of `a > b ? i : j;` in my code. Thank you to all the people who contributed to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can just make a simple function to do the work (this syntax isn't 100% right, but you should get the idea):

```
reducedFunction(int numRows, int numImages, bool[][] tracker) {
    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numImages; j++) {
            imageView[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tracker[i-1][j-1] == false) {
                        tracker[i-1][j-1] = true;
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.launcher);
                    } else {
                        tracker[i-1][j-1] = false;
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                    }
        }
    }
}

if(screenWidth > screenHeight) {
    reducedFunction(numLandscapeRows, numLandscapeImagesPerRow, imageViewLandscapeTracker)
}
else {
    reducedFunction(numPortraitRows, numPortraitImagesPerRow, imageViewPortraitTracker)
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer. I think this will work pretty well. Let me try it out. Also, can I also pass a third parameter into reducedFunction that's called whichTrackertoUse[][]?

Comment: You could make the argument list smaller and instead use `tracker.length` for `numRows` and `tracker[i].length` for `numImages` in the loops.

Comment: I think I'm wrong about passing the third parameter in the reducedFunction. The imageViewTracker is in a nested function or something. I'm not sure how to describe it. But I don't think I can alter the onClick() function's parameters to accept a boolean[][] parameter.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be nearly idententical.

```
int maxRows = screenWidth > screenHeight ? numLandscapeRows : numPortraitRows;
int maxCols = screenWidth > screenHeight ? numPortraitImagesPerRow :  numPortraitImagesPerRow;

TableRow tableRow[] = new TableRow[numPortraitRows];
ImageView imageView[] = new ImageView[numPortraitImagesPerRow];

for (i = 0; i < maxRows ; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < maxCols ; j++) {
        imageView[j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1]) {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                    } else {
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.launcher);
                    }
                    imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1] = imageViewPortraitTracker[i-1][j-1]
                 }
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. They're almost identical except for the constants that I use depending on whether the android phone is in portrait mode or in landscape mode. I used the if else statement to separate the code that handles each situation. But I was hoping there would be some way to combine the code and still allow it to handle each situation.

Comment: Thanks for your `a > b ? i : j;` suggestion. I used it to simplify my code. I ended up mostly using the reducedFunction idea mentioned by Jared, though.